# Using openID Steamauthentification in cakePHP 3

Tags: php, cakephp, openid, cakephp-3.0

I try to get OpenID Steamauthentification working in my cakePHP3 app using this as my source: https://github.com/SmItH197/SteamAuthentication

I made a new Authenticate Component and it works fine but i had to add some lines of code (marked with //+) which just dont make sense in my view:

```
    public function authenticate(Request $request, Response $response)
    {

        $openid = new \LightOpenID($steamauth['domainname']);

        debug($openid);//+
        if (!$openid->mode) {
            $openid->identity = 'http://steamcommunity.com/openid';
            header('Location: ' . $openid->authUrl());
            $openid->authUrl();//+
            debug($openid);//+
        } elseif ($openid->mode == 'cancel') {
            echo 'User has canceled authentication!';
        } else {
            if ($openid->validate()) {
                $id = $openid->identity;
                $ptn = "/^http:\/\/steamcommunity\.com\/openid\/id\/(7[0-9]{15,25}+)$/";
                preg_match($ptn, $id, $matches);

                debug($matches[1]);// steam id
                return $matches;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

So without those 3 lines it doesnt work. debug is returning the variable itself and authUrl() is returning an Url String.
Does anyone have an idea why i have to return the variables to get this running? Could this be a PHP7 issue?

The appropriate method can be found in the githubrep file steamauth.php.

Answer (score 1):

**authUrl()** : is the Authenticate url request for according to your Auth Version [Check here Line 854](https://github.com/SmItH197/SteamAuthentication/blob/master/steamauth/openid.php)

**function return** : Function Return mostly **TRUE** and **FALSE** if any data return then it works as true; if not then it returns as false.

In your case, if you return TRUE

```
return true;
```

instate of

```
 return $matches;
```

it also should also work